# Discord.py UI send selectionOption when clicking button. (Version = DPY 2.0a)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@client.tree.command(name = "roles", description = "Role Test Menu.", guild =TEST_GUILD)
async def roles(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(view=RoleButton(), ephemeral = True)
##################################################################################################
class RoleButton(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
    @discord.ui.button(label='Role Menu', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id='Role Menu')
    async def rolebutton(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        test1 = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, name='Test1')
        test2 = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, name='Test2')
        if test1 in interaction.user.roles:
            df = True
        elif test2 in interaction.user.roles:
            df = True
        else:
            df = False
        options = [
            discord.SelectOption(label="Test 1", value="Test 1", default = df),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Test 2", value="Test 2", default = df)
        ]
        @discord.ui.select(placeholder="Select",custom_id="test",max_values=2, options=options)
        async def _action_select(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, select: discord.ui.Select):
            await interaction.response.send_message("Done!", ephemeral = True)
##################################################################################################
```

So, this obviously doesn't work, and I know that. But this is an example of what I am trying to do; essentially, I want the slash command to send the "Role Menu" button. Then when it it clicked by a user, check if the user has "test1" and "test2" roles. If they do/don't, then set the default selectionOption to T/F, then send the select. How can I change this to have it work how I want it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a `ui.Button` or a `ui.Select` to a message, you need a `ui.View` to which you add those things. The view then gets added to the message.

#### Solution:

```py
import discord
from discord import ui

bot = commands.Bot()

class Select(ui.Select):
    def __init__(self, options):

        # placeholder: Will be shown when no option is chosen
        # custom_id: The id of the select menu
        # options: The dropdown options which can be chosen
        # max_values: Indicates that max. 2 options can be picked
        super().__init__(placeholder="Select", custom_id="test", options=options, max_values=2)

    # This function is called when the user has chosen an option
    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        # With the interaction parameter, you can send a response message.
        # With self.values you get a list of the user's selected options.
        print(self.values)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Done!", ephemeral=True)

class ViewButton(ui.View):

    # label: The label of the button which is displayed
    # style: The background color of the button
    @ui.button(label="Role Menu", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    async def role_menu_btn(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button_obj: ui.Button):
        # This function is called when a user clicks on the button

        # get the roles
        test1_role = interaction.guild.get_role(1007237710295081020)
        test2_role = interaction.guild.get_role(1007237773230620728)

        # check if user has the role or not
        df1 = True if test1_role in interaction.user.roles else False
        df2 = True if test2_role in interaction.user.roles else False
        options = [
            discord.SelectOption(label="Test 1", value="Test 1", default=df1),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Test 2", value="Test 2", default=df2)
        ]

        # create ui.Select instance and add it to a new view
        select = Select(options=options)
        view_select = ui.View()
        view_select.add_item(select)

        # edit the message with the new view
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content="Choose an option", view=view_select)


@bot.tree.command(name="btn", description="Wonderful button")
async def btn(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Click it!", view=ViewButton())
```

---

###### References:

- [`ui.View`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?%20interaction#discord.ui.View)
- [`ui.button`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?%20modal#discord.ui.button)
- [`ui.Select`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?%20modal#discord.ui.Select)

Comment: Hi @puncher, thank you for the response! How would I go about having the Select timeout as None so the button works even after bot restart?

Comment: @Jake, no problem! You would have to store it somewhere e.g. in a database, because it will only work during the command execution. So you could store the message ID and the custom ID of the button and use the event `on_interaction`. If `on_interaction` is called you can check if it's this custom ID and the message ID of the interaction message.

Comment: `class SelectView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.add_item(Select())`
So if I were to do this to store it, I would get an error of options is not a valid argument because it only takes "Self". Where would you think I should put it? @puncher

Comment: With store, I mean in a database or at least in a json file

Comment: To store other views that I have to have a timeout as None, I use the below in the bot startup. 
`async def setup_hook(self) -> None:
        self.add_view(DropdownView())`
So I was thinking of something like this instead of storing it in a database. @puncher

Comment: You don't know the message ID. You have to store at least the message ID

Comment: @Jake If you don't mind you can still accept/upvote this post

Comment: I got you, thank you.

Comment: Hey @puncher I again appreciate the help. I forgot to ask something else, but made a new question since that was easier. Check it out since the majority is your code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73337594/checks-to-add-remove-roles-in-discord-py-2-0a-based-on-interaction-callback.